# Python: is_correct_sequence (no doubles)

Tags: python

```
def is_correct_sequence(seq):
    """
    Check whether the given sequence does not contain
    the same value (except for None) more than once,
    and whether it only contains (1) integer values between 1
    and the length of the given sequence and/or (2) the special value None.
    """

    for i in range(len(seq)):
        if seq[i] < 1 or seq[i] > len(seq):
           return False
        elif type(seq[i]) != type(None) or type(seq[i]) != int:
            return False
        else:
            for i in range(len(seq)-1):
               for j in range(i+1, len(seq)):
                  if seq[i] == seq[j] != None:
                     return False
                  else:
                     return True

##TESTS

assert not is_correct_sequence((4, "abc", None, -17, None, "xyz"))
assert not is_correct_sequence((1, 2, 1))
assert not is_correct_sequence((1.0, None, 1))
assert is_correct_sequence((None, None, 4, 1))
assert is_correct_sequence((None, 1, 2, 3))
```

I have problems with the last 2 asserts.So the goal is not to remove doubles, but to see if the sequence is correct or not. The sequence is not correct if two of its elements  are the same, except for None (None may appear several times). How do I make this clear in my code ?

Comment: In every condition, you have a `return` clause. You never do more than one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your code.

One major problem is that you never actually check every element more than once -- when your code hits a "return" statement, it immediately returns, and doesn't check every other statement. That works when you need to return `False` since if anything is ever `False`, you don't need to check the rest of the sequence.

However, it *is* a problem in the line when you're returning `True`, since you haven't ruled out that the subsequence could be incorrect later on.

Another problem was that your conditions in your if statements were subtly off - try taking a closer look and trace out what they're actually doing. Taking those into account, the correct version of your code would be:

```
def is_correct_sequence(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        if seq[i] is not None and (seq[i] <= 1 and seq[i] >= len(seq)):
            # This check previously failed if seq[i] was None, and did not
            # check the bounds properly
            return False
        elif seq[i] is not None and type(seq[i]) != int:
            # Use 'and', not 'or'
            return False
        else:
            for i in range(len(seq)-1):
                for j in range(i+1, len(seq)):
                    if seq[i] == seq[j] and seq[i] is not None and seq[j] is not None:
                        # Again, same thing. This failed if either seq[i] or seq[j]
                        # were not equal to None
                        return False
    return True
```

As noted in the code, your main problem was not checking to see if an item was equal to None. if it is, you'll get odd results when comparing it against a number.

Incidentally, the correct way to check if an element is `None` or not `None` in Python is the idiom `item is None` or `item is not None`.

However, a more concise way of writing your code might be this:

```
def is_correct_sequence(seq):
    nums = [a for a in seq if a is not None]
    allowed_types = (type(None), int)

    contains_correct_types = all(isinstance(a, allowed_types) for a in seq)
    numbers_within_bounds = all(1 <= a <= len(seq) for a in nums)
    numbers_are_unique = len(nums) == len(set(nums))
    # Set returns a version of a list with all duplicates removed

    return contains_correct_types and numbers_within_bounds and numbers_are_unique
```

Instead of using a for loop, we can use list comprehensions and generator comprehensions as well as the builtin `any` and `all` functions to more clearly express the intent of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try going through the following approach and see if it makes sense. I've tested it only with the assertions you have provided and it seems to work.

```
def is_correct_sequence(seq):
    return has_unique_values(seq) and has_correct_range(seq)

def has_unique_values(seq):
    """
    Check whether sequence contains the same value (excluding None) more than once

    Returns True if all values are unique or None, False otherwise.
    """

    nones = seq.count(None)
    seq_set = set(seq)

    if nones:
        if len(seq) != (len(seq_set) + nones - 1):
            return False
    else:
        if len(seq) != len(seq_set):
            return False

    return True

def has_correct_range(seq):
    """
    Check whether sequence contains integer values between 1 and the length
    of the given sequence and/or the special value None.
    """

    accepted_range = range(1, len(seq) + 1)
    for e in seq:
        if e not in accepted_range and e is not None:
            return False

    return True

assert not is_correct_sequence((4, "abc", None, -17, None, "xyz"))
assert not is_correct_sequence((1, 2, 1))
assert not is_correct_sequence((1.0, None, 1))
assert is_correct_sequence((None, None, 4, 1))
assert is_correct_sequence((None, 1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compact version that passes all asserts:

```
from collections import Counter

def is_correct_sequence(seq):

    len_seq = len(seq)
    counts = Counter(seq)

    for value, count in counts.items():

        # Never check None items
        if (value is not None and (

            # Does the value occur more than once
            # or has it a bad type (no integer)?
            (count > 1 or not isinstance(value, int)) or

            # Or is the integer not in the valid range?
            (value < 1 or value > len_seq))
            ):

            # Sequence is in correct!
            return False

    return True


assert not is_correct_sequence((4, "abc", None, -17, None, "xyz"))
assert not is_correct_sequence((1, 2, 1))
assert not is_correct_sequence((1.0, None, 1))
assert is_correct_sequence((None, None, 4, 1))
assert is_correct_sequence((None, 1, 2, 3))
```

You should use

- `isinstance()` for type checks
- `is None` / `is not None` instead of `== None` / `!= None`
- No nested loops for such simple tests (`collections.Counter` should make my solution pretty efficient)